# How to Increase Landscape Image Resolution in .png output?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

Situation: unable to increase landscape resolution in the .png output of `export_fig`
Goal: get more and more landscape resolution after each iteration

I can increase the amount of points in the matrix (`time`) determining the y-axis direction. 
The time-axis has 2x more points in each iteration. The `export_fig`'s output remains as square in each iteration, causing the amplitude of the peaks to be smaller and smaller in each iteration. 
Pseudocode

```
counter=1;
while (counter < 4);
    potential=linspace(0,100, 200);
    timeEndSeconds=counter*10;
    time=linspace(0, timeEndSeconds, 2*timeEndSeconds);

    % computere here anything to the presentation etc Sin
    %Presentation = sin(time); % gives dimensions 1x20, but should be 1x200 i.e. asserted by potential`s linspace but not sure how to ensure it

    width=50; 
    height=50; 
    figure('Position', [100 100 width height]);

    imagesc(time, potential, Presentation);

    filename=fullfile('/home/masi/Desktop/', counter);
    % https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig
    % TODO ensure here the specific resolution in time x potential for the image
    export_fig(filename, '-png','-dpng', gcf);

    counter=counter+1;
end
```

I could not find anything about the resolution of the y-axis in the documentation, when studying the options.

### Proposal based on Suever's comment

Have the following in the loop, which doubles the image resolution

```
% Use swap as described in http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388
if (counter > 1)
    height=50; 
    width=50*counter;
    set(gcf, 'Position', [100 100 width height]);
end
```

Open

- `linspace` better integration to `Position` in `figure`?

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Matlab: 2016a
Documentation: [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid

Comment: so you want the exported `png` to have more pixels of width each time? e.g. in the beginning it is 300x400 but then after a while 300x800?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `export_fig` you just need adjust the size of your figure or alter the `ylims` of the axes

Comment: @Ander yes,  you are right

Comment: @Suever Yes, you are right. See the body. Is there any benefit of `lims` here? I think just resizing figure can be problematic in dynamic cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suever's answer: adjust size of your figure. 
There are better environments for dynamic situations, etc use Mathematica in those cases.